# What is an unimodular problem?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, total-unimodularity

Given an optimization problem below:
$$ \min_{Y^m_{ij} \in \{0,1\}} \sum_{p \in P} \sum_{(i,j)\in A} \sum_{c \in C} n^c \rho_{ij}^{p,m(c)} X_{ij}^c\\
\text{where } X_{ij}^c \text{ solves:}\\ 
\min \sum_{c \in C} \sum_{(i,j) \in A} n^c l_{ij} X_{ij}^c\\
\text{s.t. }\\
\sum_{(i,k) \in A} X_{ik}^c - \sum_{(k,i) \in A} X_{ki}^c =  
\begin{cases}
   +1, &\text{if } i = o(c)\\
   -1, &\text{if } i = d(c), \forall i \in N, c \in C\\
   0, &\text{o.w}
\end{cases}\\
X_{ij}^c \leq Y_{ij}^{m(c)} \;\; \forall (i,j) \in A, c \in C\\
X_{ij}^c \in \{0,1\} \;\; \forall (i,j) \in A, c \in C $$

with $n^c, \rho_{ij}^{p,m(c)},$ and $ l_{ij}$ as parameters.

It is stated that "Once the $Y_{ij}^m$ values are given, the inner problem is unimodular. Hence, the integrality requirements ($X_{ij}^c \in \{0,1\}$) can be replaced by $X_{ij}^c \geq 0$ without the loss of optimality.

**Question**: What does unimodular mean in this problem? How does it affect the integrality requirements $X_{ij}^c$?

**What I know**: I found a definition that states; "A matrix A is totally unimodular if every square submatrix of A has determinant +1,-1, or 0." But I'm not sure how to use that definition in the problem above.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: About your last section. The definition is also for an [*unimodular* matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix). So there is no need to consider only "totally" unimodular matrices.  And otherwise I found a paper [Finding total unimodularity in optimization problems solved by linear programs](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.507.8438&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which uses this for the *constraint matrix* to be (totally) unimodular.

Comment: For a matrix, unimodular and totally unimodular are distinct notions. Here, the relevant one is indeed total unimodularity (TU): if the constraint matrix of a linear program is TU and the bounding vector is integral, then for any objective function for which the optimum exists, there will be an integral optimal solution.